# subgroup analysis in complex mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, random-effects-model

I have a dataset of the information on all students in a number of schools drawn from a number of cities. To check the interaction of student gender on variables X and variables Y in the dataset, I have built models using the lmer function in lme4 package like this:

```
model<-lmer(y~x+gender+gender:x+covariates+1|school_ID/city_ID,data=dataset)
```

And for subgroup analysis, I built models like this:

```
#same "covarites" as the above model
model1<-lmer(y~x+covariates+1|school_ID/city_ID,data=dataset[dataset$gender=='male',])
model2<-lmer(y~x+covariates+1|school_ID/city_ID,data=dataset[dataset$gender=='female',])
```

And then contradictory findings were found for certain combinations of x and y: (1) The p of the gender:x term is less than 0.05, while the 95% confidence interval(CI) of the estimate of x in model1 contains exactly its 95% CI in model2; (2) The p of the gender:x term is bigger than 0.05, while the 95% CI of the estimate of x in model1 does not overlap with its 95% CI in model2.

I wonder why these contradictory results happen? Is it because the complex mixed-effects model is sensitive to changes in sample size (i.e. because of the split of the dataset in subgroup analysis)? If so, how can I obtain the estimates of x and its 95% CI by each level of the moderator (gender) without splitting the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear how the two models would run with the m variable if you have removed the variability of that variable by restricting to subsets in which that variable becomes a constant.

Comment: Did you consider testing interactions with gender in `model` instead of splitting the dataset and trying to understand why you get these differences?

Comment: @ErikRuzek Thanks for your attention, I have made some small changes to my post to make it clear. Actually m is the proxy of variable gender. Yes, the p for the gender:x term is contradictory to the results of x in the subgroups analysis of model1 and model2.

Comment: @GreggH Thanks for your attention, I have made some small changes to the codes in my post to make it clearer. Actually m is the proxy of variable gender.

Comment: If m is a proxy for gender, it still will not have any variability if you restrict to the gender subgroups.

Comment: At what level of the hierarchy is the x variable measured? If it is at the school or city level, then you need to allow the slope of gender to vary across schools or cities. Otherwise the p-value you get out of `model` is too liberal. In terms of why the results differ, it's hard to say. Conceptually, you are splitting up coherent higher level units (mixed-sex schools and neighborhoods) and then running a model where you've removed opposite sex students. The random intercept variance estimates are going to be quite different and it's not clear that the models are conceptually the same.